# Force a page break and including headers when using cfdocument?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, page-break, cfdocument

I'm generating a `<table>` and converting it to PDF using `<cfdocument>`. I would like to include the table header on the new page when it runs over. This is around every 30th line.

Here is my current code. The `<cfif>` is supposed to force a break at every new line. However, all it seems to do is create 4 blank pages with the content at the bottom, formatted the same as it was before

```
<cfloop query="One">

    <cfif not(One.currentrow MOD 30)>
        <cfdocumentitem type="pagebreak" />
        <th>Contact Name</th>
     </cfif>

     <cfoutput> 
        #One.contactName# 
     </cfoutput>
```

Comment: have you looked at the html without the cfdocument tag.  This isn't all your code (which makes it hard for us to help you) but if it is close you have a very **very** malformed table that could be making cfdocument/iText cry for mommy.

Comment: Comment out the cfdocument and cfdocumentitem tags.  view the source, you should have `<table><tr><th></th></tr>` 29 `<tr><td></td></tr>` 1 `<tr><th></th></tr>` 29 `<tr><td></td></tr>` 1 `<tr><th></th></tr>` etc, then your closing `</table>` after you get the html straight, uncomment the cfdocument tags and see what you get.

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question a couple of days ago?

Comment: nah, he asked a similar question, now he needs help implementing the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Here is what I used to get my header on every page. Further note, if you need to adjust the document header size, then include margintop="2.2" in your main  tag and adjust to taste.

```
 <cfdocumentitem type="header" evalAtPrint="true" > 
        <td>Contact Name</td>
 </cfdocumentitem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This: This is the solution that i got.

```
<cfloop query="get_list">

<!---7 row each page--->
<cfset mode = get_list.currentrow mod 7>


<cfif mode eq 1>

<thead>
<tr>
<td>table header</td>
</tr>
</thead>

</cfif>

<tbody>

<tr>
<td>data loop here</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<cfif mode eq 0>
<cfdocumentitem type="pagebreak">
</cfdocumentitem>
</cfif>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</cfloop>

</table>
```